# Slide down vertical menu without pushing horizontal from submenus

Tags: javascript, css, drop-down-menu, menu

I have a menu list that is floated left for the main headings:

[image: main menu]

When a menu item with a submenu has a hover state, the submenu drops down, but pushes the menu to the right if it is wider than the main heading (spacing between 'shop' and 'about' -- as expected I suppose):

[image: sub menu]

I'm trying to get the submenu to maintain its height (to push down the content below it on the page), but not push the items to the right over based on its width.

Using `position: absolute` just ignores the height of the submenu when its open.

Hoping there is something I'm missing.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: easier if you could link the actual site

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/sswany/Qv3GZ/](http://jsfiddle.net/sswany/Qv3GZ/) Heres the example where it pushes to the side.  [http://jsfiddle.net/sswany/35dEr/](http://jsfiddle.net/sswany/35dEr/) Heres the example where it maintains position but doesn't push the content below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the width of the submenu to be that of the parent menu and then setting:

```
text-overflow: inherit;
overflow: visible;
```

On the submenu

Comment: Thanks Royce!  I looked into that method but was having problems with it working.  However, in the process stumbled across adding `white-space: nowrap;` and setting a nominal width that is smaller than the headings will be to the submenu seems to fix it as well!  Here is the updated Fiddle showing it: [http://jsfiddle.net/sswany/Qv3GZ/8/](http://jsfiddle.net/sswany/Qv3GZ/8/)

Comment: I forgot to add that css attribute, sorry about that. Glad to see you found it okay.

Answer (score 0):

I would position the sub menu dynamically and set its position to absolute. You will have to get the menu buttons left position and height and then set the sub menus left and its top to the height of its parent. Don't forget to use offset() to get the left position in case the menu is embedded in another container on the page.

Comment: What about pushing the content below the menu section down?  If I set the submenu to `position: absolute;` its just been display overtop of it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that pushing the content downward can be done (only?) via javascript. Here is [the updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/35dEr/4/) and its source:

JS:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("li.drop").hover(function(){
        $(this).addClass("hover");
        $('#nav').css('height', $(this).children('ul:first').height()+30+'px');
    }, function(){
        $(this).removeClass("hover");
        $('#nav').css('height', '');
    });
});
```

CSS:

```css
#nav > li {
    position:relative;
    display:inline;
    margin:0px 15px;
    padding:0;
}

#nav > li ul {
    display: none;
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:0;
    min-width:200px;
}
#nav > li.hover ul {
    display: block;
}

#content {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background: grey;
}

#nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding:0;
}
```

Comment: that's awesome!  Thanks Stano.  This is the way I'm leaning.